# jquery tooltip image preview not suitable with images of large size

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement jquery image tooltip http://cssglobe.com/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery/.I am trying to implement the plugin which display an image when mouse over a link.But this doesnt seem to be working fine if images are of large size.Can anyone help me with fitting any imag into a small viewable size without loosing aspect ratio of the image and functionalities of the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the `#screenshot` rule by adding `max-width:250px` (*change 250 to the max width you want to allow*)
Then add a rule

```
#screenshot img{max-width:100%;}
```

so the images will scale down to fit in the container.

This works with the 3rd plugin. The 2nd plugin uses a different `id` for the tool-tip/preview so you should target the tooltip and img with `#preview` and `#preview img` respectively.

---

Another option though is to create scaled down versions of the images for the tooltip, in order to minimize the wasted bandwidth.